# Trying to execute multiple layout from single class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to execute more then one layout screens from single class using onClick() method
Here goes my code

```
Button bt1,bt2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
onClick(); //onClick(View) in MainActivity cannot be applied to ()
}
public void onClick(View v){
if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
setContentView(R.layout.next1);
}
 else if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
setContentView(R.layout.next1);
}
}
```

Kindly help me out, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment is what you have to use, in this case. Load either of the fragment based on button click.

If you go for `setContentView` in this scenario, then your code will be clumsy and it will be very tedious for you to keep track on view.